# How to zoom image on Unity UI to particular point where mouse cursor is located?

Tags: unity, c#, gui, ui-design, unity-ui

I have some RectTransform on Unity UI. I have already implemented some Zoom functionality but now I need it to zoom to the area where the mouse cursor is located. Currently, it zooms to the anchor point. How can I zoom to the mouse cursor?

Here are some screenshots from a hierarchy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have already implemented zoom itself.

public class ZoomableRect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform rectToZoom;

```
[SerializeField] private ZoomConfigs zoomConfigs;

private bool onObj = false;

[SerializeField] private ScrollRect scrollRect;
public ScrollRect ScrollRect
{
    get { return scrollRect; }
    set { scrollRect = value; }
}

private bool isZoomAllowed;
public bool IsZoomAllowed
{
    get { return isZoomAllowed; }
    set { isZoomAllowed = value; }
}

private bool isFullScreen;
public bool IsFullScreen
{
    get { return isFullScreen; }
    set { isFullScreen = value; }
}

void Start()
{
    if (!rectToZoom)
        rectToZoom = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

}

void Update()
{
    float scrollWheel = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    if (isZoomAllowed && scrollWheel != 0)
    {
        ChangeZoom(scrollWheel);
        SetPosition(Input.mousePosition);
    }
}

private void ChangeZoom(float scrollWheel)
{
    float rate = 1 + zoomConfigs.zoomRate * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;

    if (scrollWheel > 0)
    {
        SetZoom(Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.y / rate,
         zoomConfigs.minSize, zoomConfigs.maxSize));
    }
    else
    {
        SetZoom(Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.y * rate,
         zoomConfigs.minSize, zoomConfigs.maxSize));
    }
}

private void SetZoom(float targetSize)
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(targetSize, targetSize, 1);
}

public void SetPosition(Vector2 mouseInput)
{
    float rectWidth = rectToZoom.rect.width;
    float rectHeight = rectToZoom.rect.height;

    float mousePosX = mouseInput.x;
    float mousePosY = mouseInput.y;

    float widthPivot = mousePosX / rectWidth;
    float heightPivot = mousePosY / rectHeight;

    Debug.Log("widthPivot = " + widthPivot + " heightPivot = " + heightPivot);

    rectToZoom.anchorMin = new Vector2(widthPivot, heightPivot);
    rectToZoom.anchorMax = new Vector2(widthPivot, heightPivot);

    rectToZoom.transform.position = new Vector2(mousePosX, mousePosY);
    Debug.Log("MousePosX = " + mousePosX + " MousePosY = " + mousePosY);
}

public void SetAnchors(bool isFullScreen)
{
    if (!isFullScreen)
    {
        rectToZoom.anchorMin = new Vector2(1, 1);
        rectToZoom.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    }
}
```

}

But anchors always snap to the bottom left corner. And widthPivot and heigtPivot values are always bigger than 1.

Actually, after testing, I see that anchors are less than 1 when the cursor is located in the bottom left part of the screen. And bigger than 1 when the cursor is in the top right part of the screen.

When zooming it always snaps to the bottom left corner.

[image]

[image]

It seems that mouse position connected to the current resolution at the same time canvas on which zoomableRect is potisioned has reference resolution of 1920 x 1080.

Changing a pivot in the same way instead of anchors doesn't have any effect. Same result.

Comment: Knowing a bit more about how your hierarchy is structured and how you've configured your transform properties like anchors would help us get more accurate answers. There are a lot of moving parts in UI layout, so if we don't account for all of them we might not get the desired effect. ;)

Comment: I have updated the info about this issue :)